# Hibernate @OneToMany - mapping to multiple join tables

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

Consider the following domain model:

```
Issue
- id
- List<Comment>

Entry
- id
- List<Comment>

Comment
-id
-comment
```

In my design, I was attempting to create two join tables to manage the associations; issue_comments, and entry_comments.  I assumed @OneToMany on Issue & Entry, but how do you map the multiple join tables? Using hibernate annotations, how can this be mapped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change your domain model, take a look at answer given by [cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18393/cletus). You'll only have one table to update so it'll provide better performance.

If you cannot change your domain model, you can map your `comment` collections via join tables:

```
// ENTRY
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="ENTRY_COMMENTS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="entry_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="comment_id")
)
public List<Comment> getComments()

// ISSUE
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="ISSUE_COMMENTS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="issue_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="comment_id")
)
public List<Comment> getComments()
```

Your comments would still be in the same table for both issues and entries; only join tables will be different. Note that this is a uni-directional relationship. Details are [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association-collections)

Answer (score 1):

This is what's known as an exclusive arc. Don't do it. Instead do this:

```
Post (id, List<Comment>)
Issue extends Post
Entry extends Post
Comment (id, comment)
```

In other words, create a common superclass for Issue and Entry and have the comments on that.

Comment: This would only be an exclusive arc if the association was bi-directional. Hibernate provides other ways to map one-to-many.