# Wrong Join type or missing criteria, multiple tables with one to many

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I would like to use the below join in several of my entities, however anytime I try I run into a FK issue.  I believe it is because it is using the ID column of the entity to match to the image_relation column.   Maybe I am using the wrong type of join all together?

My goal is to be able to have multiple entities each with multiple images.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "image_relation")
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Image> productOptionImageGroup;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in a somewhat related article. [Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275481/hibernate-onetomany-mapping-to-multiple-join-tables)

```
// ENTRY
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="ENTRY_COMMENTS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="entry_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="comment_id")
)
public List<Comment> getComments()

// ISSUE
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="ISSUE_COMMENTS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="issue_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="comment_id")
)
public List<Comment> getComments()
```